# Access Management Architecture

Tags: active-directory, sql-server-2008-r2, user-management, qlikview, access-rights

I have to come up with a recommendation on how to design and create access rights.
(Just to mention - I am beginner in QlikView, company where I work, decided to buy the tool).

Tale of the tape is:

- We have a production and development servers.
- What has to be cleared is how colleagues will develop dashboards/applications.
- Will they develop on local machines or using remote access
- on development server, we have created "InDevelopment" folder and
  gave access rights to two groups "Intern" and "Extern" (they can see
  all developing applications)
- it should not be alowed that every developer can see what every other developer is doing
- the security concept should be defined with Windows Active Directory
  Groups

the users are following:

1. QV Developers (in "Operations" and in "IT" department, therefore - two groups) - these users are doing loading, transformation, creating data models..
2. QV Designers (in "Operations" and in "IT" department, therefore - two groups) - these users create dashboard layouts
3. QV Users/Testers (in "Operations" and in "IT" department, therefore - two groups) - these users can see and test an app/dashboard

I have to suggest a plan how to define security, and how they should develop in the future - local vs remote i.e. development concept has to be defined - this is teh CORE question, and the reason for writing this post. I would appreciate help and suggestions concerning this matter.
(the order of the request is maybe not optimal because of the brainstorming and the lack of the big-picture from my side, another reason for asking help this way)